# How do I add a user_id to a polymorphic relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a polymorphic relationship between Posts, Videos and Comments.

What I want to add is who made the relationship between the Posts/Comments or Videos/Comments.  Essentially add a userId to the comments table.

Currently I have

```
user
    id - integer
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text

videos
    id - integer
    title - string
    url - string

comments
    id - integer
    body - text
    commentable_id - integer
    commentable_type - string
    user_id - integer
```

I can not figure out how to use eloquent to achieve what I want.  I have followed the docs and added the `morph` relationships as per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) but I can't seem to find a way for the user_id to be saved into the comments table as well.

How do I use eloquent to also save the user_id each time the polymorphic relationship is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent) to set data on new records right before they are saved to the database. Within your `Comment` model, add the following method:

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function($comment) {
        $comment->user_id = auth()->id();
    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, The issue I came across was when I wrote my tests I had to add an if statement to only do this if we have a user.

Answer (score 0):

In you controller for creating comments:

```
$newComment = new Comment;
...
$newComment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$newComment->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you create the Comment? If you do something like `Comment::create(['user_id' => auth()->user->id])`. Remeber to have added `user_id` to your fillable array on the Comment model.

Else you can use

```
$comment = new Comment();
$comment->user_id =  auth()->user->id;
$comment->save()
etc...
```